# Why won't "npm install prompt-sync" command work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, prompt

I’m a beginner and wanted to install prompt-sync and test it out before I start any projects. I installed it through terminal and it and then ran the code and got the message: “Error: Cannot find module ’prompt-sync’”.

I then tried to install it through Command Prompt and it said it’s up to date. So I ran the code again and got the same message. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code and node and still nothing. I tried searching here on stack, Google, YouTube and can’t figure it out. One person had the same question on Microsoft but no one answered their question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723489/why-the-npm-install-prompt-sync-command-is-not-wor

I would really appreciate any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeUSo.png)

Comment: Does your project have a package.json with dependencies defined? If you're installing it locally, there would be a `node_modules/prompt-sync/index.js` file present. If you installed it globally (this does make a difference!), it would be installed somewhere else. Also check if you're maybe running different versions of node.js.

Comment: @timotgl I have the file in my computer and it works when I put the code on that file and run but it won't work on any other file. I tried both versions of node.js. The 18.17.0 verision and the 20.5.0 version and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

there will be a file node_module name and also a json file just copy it to a folder where you want work it will work if you install NPM prompt-sync module